Do Apache Arrow compute functions use multiple CPU cores?
Functions like sum, mean, min, max, and count can be designed to be parallelized across chunks of data. I expected Apache Arrow compute functions to utilize multiple CPU cores because of that.
I did some experiments like
[arr](){return arrow::compute::MinMax(arr).ValueOrDie();

vs
[arr](){return arrow::compute::MinMax(
        arr,
        arrow::compute::ScalarAggregateOptions(),
        arrow::compute::threaded_exec_context()).ValueOrDie();

I found out the times are the same in all the experiments. Also, htop shows that there was only one CPU core in use.
So I wonder if Apache Arrow compute functions (maybe only some of them) are able to use more than one CPU core when available. Maybe there is setting for that (beside the arrow::SetCpuThreadPoolCapacity function)?
